# How can i add a breadcrumb to an existing JSON+LD list

Tags: javascript, schema, breadcrumbs

I have a JSON+LD object and I need to dynamically add items to the list element. If I start with this code:

```
var jsonObj = {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
    "itemListElement":
    [
        {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 1,
            "item":
            {
                "@id": "http://domain.com/",
                "name": "Home"
            }
        },
        {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 2,
            "item":
            {
                "@id": "http://domain.com/used-equipment/",
                "name": "Used Equipment"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I add another item in position 3 using JavaScript? Is that even possible?

Comment: Where is the JSON? It seems that you've a regular JS object, and the "list element" is an array. Hence you can do something like `jsonObj.itemListElement.push({...});`

Comment: Can you do that after the initial page load? I need to add to the list after receiving new data from a web service

Comment: Yes, if you can access the `jsonObj` within the function, which receives the data.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the input guys, it's much appreciated. However, I'm having a bigger problem. Unless I wrap this code in script tags and put the type as "application//ld+json", Google's Structured Data Testing Tool is not seeing it. So having it as it is above won't work for me. :/

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you add it just like you did the first two:

```
[
    {
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 1,
        "item":
        {
            "@id": "http://domain.com/",
            "name": "Home"
        }
    },
    {
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 2,
        "item":
        {
            "@id": "http://domain.com/used-equipment/",
            "name": "Used Equipment"
        }
    },
    {
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 3,
        "item":
        {
            "@id": "Insert URL here",
            "name": "Name of the page"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Yes, but how can I add it after the page loads, such as after receiving new data from a service? I have some products loading from a web service, so I need to add to the initial breadcrumb list after the initial page load.

Comment: @pedrom40 Then do what Teemu said. And yes, that can be done after page load since that will be Javascript code running.